# How to install the NVIDA drivers through text mode?

Tags: nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install extra drivers via the command prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22118/can-i-install-extra-drivers-via-the-command-prompt)

Due to a major problem with Ubuntu and Nouveau, my machine will end up with text-mode only.

So, my question is. how can I install the NVIDA driver through text-mode? What commands do I need (and can you list them in order, please?) Assume I'm working on a wired connection.

My apologies, but text mode leaves me a little stumped. I got 10.10 working by upgrading from 9.10 -> 10.04 -> 10.10. I'd rather I didn't have to keep doing this, nor spend money I don't have.