# Can I install extra drivers via the command prompt?

Tags: command-line, drivers

Since I can't seem to open the *Additional Drivers* program? And how do I know what driver I need to install?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### For 12.04 and below

The additional drivers program has a command line interface, `jockey-text`:

Use

```
jockey-text --list
```

to get a list of available drivers and their status, then use

```
# the init lines are required only for graphics drivers
sudo init 1
jockey-text --enable=DRIVER
sudo init 2
```

where DRIVER is the one you got from the list. For example:

```
jockey-text --enable=firmware:b43
```

To install the Broadcom B43 wireless driver.

For your graphics card, you will get a choice of the proprietary driver from the manufacturer and a free alternative. You have to either restart the display server (log out and back in) or restart the system entirely (recommended).

Answer (score 125):

### For 14.04 and above

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers list
```

Will show all the driver packages which apply to your current system. You can then

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install      # on modern Ubuntu, or
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall  # on older versions.
```

to install all the packages you need, or you can do:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

to show you which devices need drivers, and their corresponding package names.

Comment: But how do you install a specific driver? Assume that `sudo ubuntu-drivers list` outputs `fglrx` and `fglrx-updates`. How do you install `fglrx-updates`?

Comment: @landroni You use `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` to get the list of packages, and then `sudo apt-get install` to install that specific package you want.

Comment: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` is deprecated so you have to `sudo apt install ` the package corresponding to the driver you want, and then probably restart your computer

Comment: @alainsanguinetti ish... the `--help` suggests that you can just use `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` (not specify which driver) and that has the same behaviour as the old `autoinstall`.

Answer (score 6):

### For 12.04 and below

The internal name of the "additional drivers" program is `jockey-gtk`. There's a console version with the same functionality called `jockey-text` in the eponymous package. It should be installed by default.

You should be able to use

```
jockey-text -l
```

to list the available drivers and something like

```
jockey-text -e xorg:nvidia-185
```

to install one of the options listed. You should select the most appropriate driver listed.

Answer (score 5):

### If you have a Nvidia graphics card:

You need to run

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

Then reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

and you should have a working system.

Comment: Is creating an xorg file still recommended? https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-driver-installed-but-not-running/76455/9

Answer (score 2):

After install nvidia driver you can regenerate xorg config for your nvidia adapter:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

Also, you can download the driver from www.nvidia.com and install it manually:

```
sudo sh ./downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-xxx.xx.xx.run
```