# Install restricted drivers in command line

Tags: command-line, wireless, drivers, proprietary, ubuntu-minimal

I'm aware there's already been [a question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22118/can-i-install-my-graphics-drivers-via-the-command-prompt) regarding Nvidia drivers, but my case is a little different. My wireless adapter's driver is proprietary, and for a minimal install, I need a command to install it. A general command for any other restricted driver that I may come across in the future would also be extremely helpful.

Comment: Do the instruction in the other answer work for you? (`--list` in particular)

Comment: No, I didn't try it since I've only one system. Is jockey-text pre-installed in Ubuntu installs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run `jockey-text`, which is the command line equivalent of the "Additional Drivers" GUI tool.

`jockey-text -h` will show you the options available.

Comment: Do I need to install anything to use it? And is it necessary to have jockey* installed for restricted drivers?

Comment: It's installed by default, and unless you plan to manually hunt down individual drivers then you need it installed to fetch the right ones.

Comment: Thou art mistaken, for executing the above code asketh me to installeth `jockey-common`.

Comment: what code? Did it ask you to install jockey-common after you ran jockey-text for the first time?

Comment: Anyway, it'd be great if I could simply locate and download only the necessary driver package for my model since `jockey` seems to be an one-time use application.

Comment: It's exaclty as you say, after I ran the command (sorry not code) it asked to me install `jockey-common`. By the way, it's actually the second time, the first time was before I installed any GUI.

Comment: ok, then what happened? Did it find the driver you needed?

Comment: Can't answer that right now. Like I commented on the question, I've got only one active system, so I can't try it out outright. What I've updated you on are just the results on a VM I'm running.

Comment: I've confirmed in a live run of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

```
jockey-text -l
```

shows what drivers are available

```
jockey-text -e <type:name>
```

enables a driver.  Only last -e seems to be used.
eg.

```
jockey-text -e kmod:wl
```

It goes quiet for a long time during which it fetches and installs the driver.
You can use

```
jockey-text -l
```

again to check that your driver is now enabled.