# Ubuntu lags on Alienware m15x

Tags: ati, alienware

I have an Alienware M15x with the following specs

Intel Core i7 920M
Ati 5870M
500GB HD
4GB RAM

I've been running Ubuntu for a while on my work computer with an second generation i3, 8gb ram and a 500gb HD and without a video card without problems for months now.

But on my laptop it lags alot. I installed the ATi drivers from the website. But when I look in my system details it says:

Graphics: VESA: BROADWAY

Shouldn't it show my 5870M?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you ever seen a popup like [this](http://cybernetnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/ubuntu-restricted-drivers-balloon.jpg) one? This is the easy way to install proprietary video drivers (I have nVidia but the procedure should be the same). Otherwise you can try [the official Ubuntu page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI) that also explains how to install Catalyst drivers. Finally, you can also look at [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27061/install-restricted-drivers-in-command-line): the command line tool to call the "restricted drivers" window from the shell should be `jockey-text`.

Comment: Yes I installed them right away. Than I downloaded the drivers from ATi website. When I downloaded  them and tried to install it told me to uninstall the old drivers first. Then I installed the newly downloaded. They didn't work so I installed the restricted drivers again, I have the feeling it is better now, but I will read the official Ubuntu page you gave me. Thanks alot :)