# ubuntu broke my computer

Tags: 12.04, installation, 12.10, drivers

About a week and a half ago I tried to update from 12.04 to 12.10 doing the sequential upgrades to get to the new OS 13.1. I downloaded 12.1 from the software center which I've been told since that the SFC was not the best place to download an upgrade. The system took a long time to download but when it finished and rebooted it stuck on a black screen. So on google in search of answers I go, what I found was this page

[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

the 4th problem on that page sounds like the issue I'm having so I followed the instructions in it, after I do a nomodeset and and ctrl + x there is a bit of a load screen, some commands flashing on the screen, then I see user log in. I log in and at this point if I was reading the solution page correctly I need to in install my graphics driver, ok, so I go here to learn how to do that from the terminal, since I am not a command line power user (I hardly know what it is).

[Can I install extra drivers via the command prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22118/can-i-install-extra-drivers-via-the-command-prompt)

I do "jockey-text --list" and what is returned is that jockey, or jockey-text is not a command or program..so basically I think I know the problem (I don't have a graphics driver) I just need help getting that downloaded and installed to my PC. this is all I know about my laptops hardware

http://www.cnet.com/laptops/toshiba-satellite-e105-s1402/4505-3121_7-33309979.html

Also If it is of any value, I did try to reinstall ubuntu before I learned that it was a driver issue, at this time my computer will not load anything from the CD or USB drives...is that related to the issues I'm having or is that a BIOS issue? help me please and thank you.

Comment: SO from that page you gave me I did the first solution and the result was..The following packages have unmet dependencies: xserver-xorg-video-intel: Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.12.99.01) E: unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. With the mesa-utils command it says that the install was good, and that it removed xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-its-quantal so I did a restart and I'm having the same issue, now when the terminal loads I see 13.04 is ready run blah blah to upgrade, should I try that and see if it works or will I have the same problem?

Comment: I would upgrade to 13.04, yes. Then try that post again.

Comment: update took ages but it finished, when i did xserver/xorg.... "the following packages have unmet dependencies: ubuntu-desktop : Depends: xorg but it is not going to be installed xserver-xorg-video-intel : Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>2:1.12.99.901) E: Unmet dependencies. try apt-get -f install with no packages (or specify a solution)."