# Ubuntu 14.04 System freezes on wakeup from suspended state

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, suspend

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04. When I resume from suspended the system freezes after I enter my password. I am forced to power off and start again. I had a similar problem on this laptop when I upgraded to 13.04 and don't recall how I fixed it.

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro quiet splash pcie_aspm=force vt.handoff=7
```

[/var/log/pm-suspend.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7334962/)

```
$ lspci -vnn | grep -A12 VGA

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GT216M [GeForce GT 230M] [10de:0a28] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:3659]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at d2000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 6000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at d3080000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
```

Comment: The system is not actually freezing. I am able to move the cursor around with the m but do nothing else. In a couple of minutes it locks me and I am able to enter my password to login. So all I can do is enter password!

Comment: Did you try accessing another tty (Ctrl+Alt+[F1|F2|..]), and resetting the display manager(unity). maybe that is the problem, considering the fact that your mouse is responding correctly.

Comment: I used compiz to reset and restart Unity and get this error.
unityo (appinfo2) <unknown>:0 g_settings_set_value: value for key 'visual-bell-type' in schema 'org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences' is outside of valid range

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I have switched from 12.10 32-bit to 14.04 64-bit, FWIW.

Comment: IMPORTANT WORKAROUND (at least I find it a major relief!): After suspending using sudo pm-suspend, the system wakes up perfectly! I refuse to work with a computer which doesn't work without suspend so this is a golden workaround for me.

Comment: sudo pm-suspend makes no difference for me.

Comment: same problem here. Maybe it's because of the nouveau drivers....

Comment: I have a similar problem.  If I suspend by any means other than closing the cover, it works fine

Comment: No matter how I suspend, I have this problem. Suspend is not an option for me as I have to reboot.

Comment: I have the same issue with my  NVIDIA Corporation GT216M [GeForce GT 230M] (rev a2)

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1314368

Comment: @LonnieBest, nvidia 331 does not solve my problem on Pavilion dv3 laptop, any idea?

Comment: @udiboy1209, Yes, the problem is that the display manager is crashing. He's essentially asking why and how to stop that from happening. Clearly, having to reset your display manager every single time you resume your laptop makes Unity unusable on a laptop...

Answer (score 1):

I installed the proprietary Nvidia drivers as given in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver) by "floppy". Voila! My system resumes from suspend without any hitch.

Comment: I have a similar problem but when I install the Nvidia driver, I have to go the Nvidia Settings and change the PRIME profile to Intel Card, in order to use the system without freezing. While it gives me a solution for the freezing screen, it brings another problem: I can't come out of Suspend or standby screen. Does it happen with your system or does it work well with the Nvidia setup? Maybe it's specific for systems with 2 video cards. Thanks in advance. The link to my question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/458832/ubuntu-14-04-not-coming-out-of-suspend-on-dell-with-nvidia-and-intel-card

Comment: I have no problems whatsoever. I did not have to go to Nvidia settings at all. I had a freezing screen only when I resumed from suspend and that has been resolved by installing the Nvidia proprietary driver.

Comment: This happens to me on a system without Nvidia, nor any proprietary drivers.