# Ubuntu 14.04 freezes after wake up

Tags: 14.04, suspend, wakeup

After wake up the login screen appears, but I cannot type the password to log in. Furthermore, the buttons on the system panel (e. g. to shut down) are disabled, so clicking does not take effect. I'm using Samsung RV509, 64 bit.

Comment: I know this is not a good solution, but it will work. Ctrl+Alt+F1 and then Ctrl+Alt+F7

Comment: Same problem here. I have a Dell Latitude E6540 with ATI HD8000 graphics card. Today I installed the proprietary driver. Since then login screen has been freezing after suspend. The problem does not occur after switching back to Intel graphics card through Catalyst Control Center, so this issue seems to be related to my proprietary driver.

Comment: I've found the solution. I shouldn't have used the open source Xorg driver instead of the proprietary Nvidia driver that seems to work correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 System freezes on wakeup from suspended state](http://askubuntu.com/questions/455639/ubuntu-14-04-system-freezes-on-wakeup-from-suspended-state)

Comment: @CiroSantilli This is not a duplicate. If you read the other question the screen freezes *after* he enters the password. Here the OP cannot even get that far.

Comment: @Seth good catch. Let's add it to the title.

Answer (score 6):

The OP provided the solution in a comment:

> I've found the solution. I shouldn't have used the open source Xorg
>   driver instead of the proprietary Nvidia driver that seems to work
>   correctly.

–  [user278680](https://askubuntu.com/users/278680/user278680) [May 11 at 16:42](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461872/ubuntu-14-04-freezes-after-wake-up#comment612900_461872)

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact problem of disabled keys & mouse after resuming from suspend.
I've managed to solve it by switching from default display drivers to the NVIDIA 331.38 drivers.
you can switch it easily on the HUD --> additional drivers.
You would need to restart after you make the change.

Comment: +1 This worked for me using the latest NVIDIA proprietary drivers.

Comment: +1 for mentioning **Software & Updates > Additional Drivers**

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Ubuntu 14.10 on GA-H81M-D3H motherboard without any separate GPU, and it's frozen after suspending randomly. All that remains is the log-in screen that you can neither move your mouse nor enter the tty mode. I figured out that the problem happened every time I triggered the audio on the system. <del>Then I went to the bios setup -> peripherals -> audio controller, and changed its settings from "auto" to "enabled". It's now working!</del>

Comment: Your issue sounds like mine, and it looks like you changed your mind on the audio controller fix... Any luck in the past couple years at fixing this?

Comment: As much as I remember, I upgraded to a newer Ubuntu version and the issue was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. Using HUD-->additional drivers, I was able to switch from the Xorg driver to the NVIDIA driver. (The number was different for mine than the 331.38 but this makes sense, I guess). Solved my problem of the login screen being frozen after waking from suspend.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, after wake up sometime i could move the mouse but the GUI was freezed and only when i pressed CTRL+ALT+F1 i could use the terminal. Other times instead it freezed totally.

After long research ( changing bios settings, grub settings, graphic drivers , DMs etc) i tried both lxde and gnome with metacity and both didn't had problems with suspend.

So i have to think that compiz is bugged with suspend mode. Try to use another desktop manager or change compiz with metacity if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I've installed the latest nvidia drivers from [here](http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/), 
 and now everything works fine.

Comment: @bta Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

found another thread where a workaround is "sudo pm-suspend". Seems to work well for me. I'm using Intel Ivy Bridge graphics.

Comment: Can you please add a link to that thread? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu Gnome 15.10. This is what worked for me:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Edit the line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash'"

Replace it with: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'"

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then you have to reboot twice. I know. You have to do it twice, though.

That fixed the issue for me, hopefully, this helps someone else.

Comment: are you sure. I didn't get, what was the matter behind this problem. How this can be solution. I am not sure.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I struggled with the issue for some time, but this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone thought the problem might be suspending with unmounted drives (partitions or USB drives) showing. I had this problem recently, and no other changes than having unmounted drives @ suspend caused the problem. When any detected drives/partitions were mounted, the suspend feature worked flawlessly. This is probably a duplicate but I'm not searching for it.
Thanks.