# after Ubuntu 14.04 update Geforce doesn't work anymore

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, updates, console

After I have updated yesterday Ubuntu 14.04 in a routine update my NVIDIA Gforce doesn't work anymore. I get the login screen but then it doesn't continue. Mouse pointer is showing, the background image but no contiuation to the full desktop. With Ctrl+Alt+F1 I can switch to the console but I don't know, how to continue, how to make an update of the driver for example.
DFuring that update the Ubuntu-core was updated an I had to reboot after that. Can it be, that the driver now doesn't fit to the Ubuntu update?
How to resolve that now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 install NVIDIA driver](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver)

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-install the NVIDIA driver by using the following commands in a console. You must first login entering your username and password.

*When you enter you password, you see nothing.*

Try the following in a console:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Then do the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And the last:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

Now reboot the system, and try if you can login.

Comment: Thanks, have got a solution already from Jorge Castro and Oli how they where answering an older question of me:

sudo ubuntu-drivers list
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall 

Those two commandlines worked perfectly! The commands found the Nvidia-card and updated the driver. Ubuntu is running again. Problem is solved.

Comment: Great to see that it is solved!