# Ubuntu 14.04 Geforce 9800 GT

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, graphics

Trying to set up ubuntu 14.04 on a system that has a Geforce 9800 GT. After installing I have tried hooking up a Dell 4k monitor. The system will boot up showing the ubuntu logo and then the screen will go dark. I have tried installing all of the nvidia drivers and none of them seem to work. I need help.

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you to check another driver for nvidia. Open the Additional Drivers utility (Dash -> Additional Drivers) and try a different version.
I have had to change it to nvidia 304 driver since Ubuntu 13.10 for a nvidia GT9800 because the same problem. If you can try this version but it is unavailable, you can install it by using this command:
sudo apt-get install nvidia-304

If the problem continues, you can try a clean installation for the nvidia driver:
[How do I install the Nvidia driver for a GeForce GT 630](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver)