# ubuntu 14.04 hangs / freezes frequently

Tags: nvidia

When I'm doing something on the desktop like using firefox and i want to minimize it and also using terminal and i want to minimize it, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS will just randomly freeze. The screen just stops, I can't see my mouse move, etc. However, I can <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> into a tty terminal (though it's not much use).

However, Sometimes through tty terminal i was able to restart but most times it was not possible. Most times i needed to force shutdown through power button.

What is going on here? How can I fix / stop / prevent this?

Note: My laptop has an nvidia-Geforce setup.

I searched similar problems in the forum and i tried so many solutions but not one solved the problem. From the forum it seems the nvidia driver is the issue but in my case it is not getting solved.

Note : I am using Gnome desktop environment.

Also when i do not do anything long time and Ubuntu lock automatically .
after that if i give pass and want to log in it also gets hang.

Comment: Are you using the workspace switcher to switch to a new workspace to undertake your other task? If you haven't enabled it you can do so from System Settings>Behaviour> and check the box Enable Workspaces.

Comment: What is your Gnome version? Have you upgraded it to 3.12 recently? Gnome 3.12 is full of bugs And that might cause such problems. Ubuntu 14.04 has Gnome 3.10 by default.

Comment: Just to add, this might just be an interim work-around but also a very useful tool for spreading tasks over different screens. To switch screens does not require the use of the mouse but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> plus one of the cursor navigation keys up, down,left or right which, without experiencing your problem, may still work.

Comment: I used this command $ gnome-session --version and found the following result:

gnome-session 3.9.90

@tiash

Comment: @NoviceUserFrance : System Settings>Behaviour> and check the box Enable Workspaces. -> this is already enabled.

Comment: @NoviceUserFrance :

No,It does not work. I enabled it few days ago.

Comment: Worthwhile knowing, thanks. Sorry I wasn't able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to check another driver for nvidia.
Open the Additional Drivers utility (Dash -> Additional Drivers) and try a different version.
I have had to change it to nvidia 304 driver since Ubuntu 13.10 for a nvidia GT9800 because the same problem. If you can try this version but it is unavailable, you can install it by using this command:
sudo apt-get install nvidia-304

Comment: this solution did not work for me

Comment: You can try to re-install nvidia driver:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver

Perhaps this link may help you to solve it:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/479504/ubuntu-14-04-crashes-after-installing-nvidia-331-or-nvidia-current-driver-gtx-7?answertab=votes#tab-top