# MacBook Air (3,2) odd Behavior when starting

Tags: 14.04, macbook, apple, macbook-air

So I partitioned my drive and installed ubuntu 14.04 on my mac. I went in ubuntu to install some proprietary drivers. Restarted my computer and this is what happened:

1. Started normally
2. Login prompt,though missing background and toolbar.
3. Once I log on,this weird light blue screen apperes with 2 error screens indicating a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access a terminal from the log-in screen (CTRL+ATL+F1)?

If so, you can try and reinstall the ubuntu-desktop package:

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

If that doesn't work, try uninstalling/reinstalling the proprietary drivers - presumably this is a nvidia issue. Part of this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver) (14) details the necessary steps.

Comment: I cannot get to the console,is there a way to boot to the console directly?