# Ran in low graphics mode

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

I ran into low graphics mode after following answer from here: [How do I install the Nvidia driver for a GeForce GT 630](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver)

Comment: nvidia offers different drivers, do you have a GT 630? Otherwise you probably need a different driver. Tell me your graphic card and I tell you the driver you need and why

Comment: I downloaded the driver from Nvidia corresponding to GT 635 and installed it

Comment: Here is a fix to your problem http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2014/07/ubuntu-1404-lenovo-g510.html

Answer (score 0):

Ironically it was a different page on this site regarding the alteration of nvidia drivers which brought me to this site today, and it is why I'm trying to get my points up.  I have a LOT TO SAY about the advice offered there, and I feel many of those giving the advice are not giving especially good advice, or specifically offering some relatively harmful advice.  Thanks to your question, I may be able to offer some of the advice here that I would have added there.

Please open a terminal and type:

> dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia

This will show you a list of what has been installed.  Removing each package you don't want is not too hard with the apt-get purge command, but you have to do it separately for each package or risk removing a package which is apparently harmful to remove, hence my desire to post a comment to that thread, as I figured out a harmless way to do that.

My advice to you or to anyone else wishing to install particular nvidia drivers without the headaches is to install the Synaptic Package Manager (which can be found in your Ubuntu Software Center, if you have not already installed it).  Once in Synaptic you can type NVIDIA and peruse all sorts of packages, but more importantly you can return there to an installation log and UNDO your previous mistake.  Being able to retrace your steps and undo your failures is a very important feature.

PERSONALLY I'm thankful I found the pages here as they helped me to remove some nvidia drivers which had been plaguing my installation for the past six months or so.  As I understand it, these drivers aren't necessarily needed anymore since apparently it is no longer necessary to use Nvidia's proprietary drivers in order to make their graphics cards work right.