# How to get rid of X server in ubuntu 14.04 in order to install nvidia drivers?

Tags: 14.04, xserver

I'm trying to run the .run files for the nvidia drivers for my gpu, but it keeps saying I must get rid of the the x server. How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 install NVIDIA driver](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to "get rid of" the X server - you just need to stop it temporarily.

First, switch to a virtual terminal using one of the key combinations <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> thru <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and log in using your regular account username and password. Then execute the command

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Once you have finished running the .run files for the drivers, you can restart the GUI using

```
sudo service lightdm start
```