# Make error on Nvidia drivers and kernel 3.17

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, kernel

I can't install **nvidia-331-updates-uvm** alongside with **kernel 3.17** on **Ubuntu 14.04**.

Here is the [make.log](http://pastebin.com/bZx4L0zB) of nvidia driver.

Has someone solved this problem ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whit the tip of [Taz D](https://askubuntu.com/a/451248/260670), I was able to run the kernel 3.17 alongside with the last [Nvidia driver](http://www.nvidia.com.br/Download/index.aspx?lang=en). Just needed to say No to dkms auto-build during the installation process.