# Console login redisplays login screen after entering password

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, gnome, login, lightdm

I attempted to login the console using 'ubuntu default' and after a very brief moment of displaying the desktop background I am returned to the login screen.

It was working flawlessly until a few days ago and yes, there have been some apt updates. However, I have also tried booting with the last-but-one version of the os. That now doesn't work either.

I have xfce window manager on this system. And that DOES work from the console.

Also I can connect in over the LAN via an SSH connection. And I use an Xserver on another MS Windows computer on the LAN and I am able to fire up 'gnome-terminal' 'gnome-system-monitor' 'thunar' 'xdaliclock' etc etc to run on the desktop of my MS Windows computers.

I have a PCI Express NVIDIA  GeForce 210 graphics card, configured using the guidance on www.nvidia.com. Some tweaking was required to get this working. The 'nouveau' driver needed to be blacklisted and IRQ 19 needed to be bypassed

I have 'googled' the diagnostic messages appearing in various places and that has led me to several 'askubuntu' questions about the same issue. However, none of the solutions discussed work for me e.g. The user .Xauthority file with wrong permissions.

Here are some of the diagnostics captured ...

Home directory ...

**.xsession-errors**

```
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Script for ibus started at run_im.
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd respawning too fast, stopped
init: gnome-session (Unity) main process (2473) terminated with status 1
init: logrotate main process (2373) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-bluetooth main process (2587) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-power main process (2590) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-datetime main process (2594) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-printers main process (2600) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-session main process (2607) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-application main process (2627) killed by TERM signal
init: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
```

**/var/log/auth.log**

```
Jan 31 19:52:13 WENLOCK polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c2 (system bus name :1.88 [/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
Jan 31 19:52:23 WENLOCK gnome-keyring-daemon[2304]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Jan 31 19:52:23 WENLOCK polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c2 (system bus name :1.88, object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Jan 31 19:52:23 WENLOCK lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session closed for user dave
Jan 31 19:52:24 WENLOCK lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jan 31 19:52:24 WENLOCK lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Jan 31 19:52:24 WENLOCK lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Jan 31 19:52:24 WENLOCK systemd-logind[933]: Removed session c1.
Jan 31 19:52:24 WENLOCK systemd-logind[933]: New session c3 of user lightdm.
Jan 31 19:52:24 WENLOCK systemd-logind[933]: Linked /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 to /run/user/104/X11-display.
Jan 31 19:52:24 WENLOCK systemd-logind[933]: Removed session c2.
Jan 31 19:52:24 WENLOCK lightdm: pam_ck_connector(lightdm-greeter:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
Jan 31 19:52:25 WENLOCK lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jan 31 19:52:25 WENLOCK lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Jan 31 19:52:25 WENLOCK lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "dave"
```

**/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log**

```
[+12.87s] DEBUG: Session pid=1850: Greeter start authentication for dave
[+12.87s] DEBUG: Session pid=1955: Started with service 'lightdm', username 'dave'
[+12.94s] DEBUG: Session pid=1955: Got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+12.94s] DEBUG: Session pid=1850: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+32.75s] DEBUG: Session pid=1850: Continue authentication
[+32.91s] DEBUG: Session pid=1955: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+32.91s] DEBUG: Session pid=1850: Authenticate result for user dave: Success
[+32.91s] DEBUG: Session pid=1850: User dave authorized
[+32.95s] DEBUG: Session pid=1850: Greeter requests session ubuntu
[+32.95s] DEBUG: Seat: Stopping greeter; display server will be re-used for user session
[+32.95s] DEBUG: Session pid=1850: Sending SIGTERM
[+33.01s] DEBUG: Session pid=1850: Exited with return value 0
[+33.01s] DEBUG: Seat: Session stopped
[+33.01s] DEBUG: Seat: Greeter stopped, running session
[+33.01s] DEBUG: Registering session with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
[+33.03s] DEBUG: Session pid=1955: Running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu
[+33.03s] DEBUG: Creating shared data dlog
irectory /var/lib/lightdm-data/dave
[+33.04s] DEBUG: Session pid=1955: Logging to .xsession-errors
```

**/var/log/dmesg**

```
[   14.499737] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[   14.499746] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   14.558177] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   14.578005] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:01:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[   14.652299] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20150116 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[   14.652314] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86 Kernel Module  340.93  Wed Aug 19 16:00:03 PDT 2015
[   15.527392] init: failsafe main process (681) killed by TERM signal
```

Answer (score 0):

you have alot of broken packages first connect with ssh and run

```
sudo apt-get -f install -y
```

test it maybe solve your problem if do not effect wait for other answer and if you want test it
note : after run it apt remove all broken pakage from your system some time removed you needed package so accuracy use it also it have low risk

> sudo apt-get autoremove

Comment: dave@WENLOCK:~$ sudo apt-get -f install -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
dave@WENLOCK:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!  I noticed the very first message in my .xsession-errors ... i.e.

**libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast**

So, I checked this out and found ...

[Problems with libGl, fbConfigs, swrast through each update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541343/problems-with-libgl-fbconfigs-swrast-through-each-update)

So... I uninstalled and re-installed the NVIDIA drivers (the process does a heap of stuff with links, libs and the X environment). I used the guidance available from NVIDIA

http://uk.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/340.93/README/installdriver.html

And everything is pretty much working again now (although I do hit an error with 'unity-greeter' just after logon. But it continues fine after reporting that).