# Failed to load NVIDIA drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, ssh

I have an [NVIDIA NVS 5200](http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-NVS-5200M.76732.0.html), and my machine is running Ubuntu 15.10. I am trying to access a software that is currently installed on a server. In order to get the window of the [software](http://www.altairhyperworks.com/product/HyperMesh), I am using the "-X" for the ssh connection. The problem is, when I try to launch it, I get this:

```
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  2501
  Current serial number in output stream:  2500
```

I have tried to completely uninstall Nvidia drivers, and reinstall them, testing different versions, but it did not fix the problem. I have tried a lot of different tutorials and the only thing I managed to do is to make unity crash. How should I proceed?

Edit: I will list the different solutions I have come across, and that did not work for me so far:

- Fully uninstall Nvidia drivers
- Install different versions of the driver. Only version 340.96 worked. Installing an other one would make it impossible for me to access my desktop (even after reinstalling desktop-ubuntu and unity)
- [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541343/problems-with-libgl-fbconfigs-swrast-through-each-update%20done), did not work for me

I'll edit the list as we go.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/541343/problems-with-libgl-fbconfigs-swrast-through-each-update seems a good start.

Comment: @Rinzwind indeed, but I already tried this one, and glxgears runs just fine for me

Comment: @Rinzwind I also retried the second answer (reinstall Nvidia  drivers), and after that, I could not log in on the desktop (happens with almost all drivers version), so I went back to the version 340.96

Comment: List what you tried. Or other users will also end up suggesting things you have tried.

Comment: @muru I tried a lot of different tutorials to solve my problem, I cannot give you all their URL, but i'll try to be more precise (cf edit main message)