# Problem running Steam on 16.04 with newest NVIDIA driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, steam

Steam is running when install I install nvidia-current (304). If I switch to the newest available 361 I get the error:

```
$ steam
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2016-06-05 18:13:15] Startup - updater built Jun 16 2014 11:16:02
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

I tried out every solution I could found like this:

[Problems with libGl, fbConfigs, swrast through each update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541343/problems-with-libgl-fbconfigs-swrast-through-each-update)

Could someone help me to track this problem down?

I have a NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M.

Comment: What graphic card do you have ?

Comment: @JonasCz added to post.