# Steam not running on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, steam

First of all, I've been trying to run Steam for the last few days. Every time I started Steam, the icon only appears for a moment, then it closes. When I checked the process through the system monitor, it is marked as sleeping. So I started it through the terminal, and it shows this:

```
$ steam
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2016-12-03 17:10:00] Startup - updater built Jun 16 2014 11:16:02
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

From what I read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771032/steam-not-opening-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts), putting the `env LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0` command before `steam`, could get it running, and it ends up like this:

```
$ env LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2016-12-03 17:12:41] Startup - updater built Jun 16 2014 11:16:02
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

I've also read fromthe same link that deleting the `libstdc++.so.6` link might make it work, but apparently the said directory does not exist in my device, which might explain why the output is same.

Would anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: "libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast" What is your GPU and what driver do you have?

Comment: @MarkKirby My GPU is NVIDIA GeForce 840M,  driver version 375.

Comment: Go in to the nvidia settings app and make sure you are using that chip and not the Intel one, in the prime section, this should fix the error.

Comment: @MarkKirby It's already set as 'NVIDIA' in the PRIME Profile when I opened the settings.

Comment: OK try changing the driver version `sudo apt-get purge nvidia* && sudo apt-get install  nvidia-340` This may help as your chip is older but you are trying a newer driver. If this does not help, see here for some debugging http://askubuntu.com/a/566522/75060 Basically, your issue is steam is trying to load the swrast software renderer and that is not good enough for steam.

Comment: FYI the file you wanted to remove is located here `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`

Comment: @MarkKirby It seems that I made a mistake, I removed `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`, and now the `apt-get` command is receiving an error.

Comment: @MarkKirby Now I'm unable to open almost any application. What should I do?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you? Where did your read to remove the file? Did you not back it up? What was the reason to remove it? IMO this needs a whole new question, as it is now far removed from a steam issue.

Comment: @MarkKirby I've resolved my mistake by copying that file from a live ubuntu disk.