# libGl, fbConfigs, swrast error in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, opengl, xvfb

Recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit desktop.

Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD OLAND (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)
When I have seen other link where they provide solution for Ubuntu with Nvidia not sure that will help since I have AMD Radeon.

```
$ xvfb-run firefox http://www.google.com
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so 
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/ram/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/ram/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[GFX1]: Unknown image format 16
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with libGl, fbConfigs, swrast through each update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541343/problems-with-libgl-fbconfigs-swrast-through-each-update)

Comment: @kenorb: I don't think the linked question and its answers are applicable to virtual xvfb screens as in this question.