# Black screen when opening Anki

Tags: drivers, graphics, opengl

When I start anki in my Ubuntu machine, this popups

[black screen popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nUMK.png)

So I tried starting Anki using terminal, and this is the error it shows.

```
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Qt warning: QQuickWidget: Failed to make context current 
Qt warning: QQuickWidget::resizeEvent() no OpenGL context 
Qt warning: QQuickWidget: Failed to make context current 
Qt warning: QQuickWidget: Failed to make context current 
Qt warning: QQuickWidget::resizeEvent() no OpenGL context 
Qt warning: QQuickWidget: Failed to make context current 
Xlib: sequence lost (0x102d1 > 0x2d3) in reply type 0x0!
Xlib: sequence lost (0x102d4 > 0x2d6) in reply type 0x0!
Qt warning: QQuickWidget: Failed to make context current 
Qt warning: QQuickWidget::resizeEvent() no OpenGL context 
Qt warning: QQuickWidget: Failed to make context current 
[21404:21447:0520/120313.269102:ERROR:context_group.cc(292)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: too few texture units supported (0, should be 8).
Qt warning: QQuickWidget: Attempted to render scene with no context 
Qt warning: QQuickWidget: Attempted to render scene with no context 
Qt warning: QQuickWidget: Attempted to render scene with no context 
[21461:7:0520/120313.271585:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(144)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuChannelMsg_CreateCommandBuffer.
[21404:21447:0520/120313.291113:ERROR:context_group.cc(292)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: too few texture units supported (0, should be 8).
Qt warning: QQuickWidget::invalidateRenderControl could not make context current 
Qt warning: QQuickWidget::invalidateRenderControl could not make context current 
Qt warning: QQuickWidget::invalidateRenderControl could not make context current
```

Specs

- OS version - Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- Graphics - AMD Radeon RX 580 Series
- Processor - AMD Ryzen 7 3800x 8-core processor × 16

I have tried reinstalling my graphic drivers but it didn't work.

Also I was trying to do this [method](https://askubuntu.com/a/566522), but I couldn't as I have very low experience with linux and my graphic card is AMD

I have also tried [this](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/509#issuecomment-282331680), but it doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Anki (2.1.54 in my case) with Qt6, try enabling software rendering:

```
echo software > ~/.local/share/Anki2/gldriver6
```

Comment: This work for Anki 2.1.60 Qt6 on Ubuntu 22.04.02 Jammy

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I encounter error messages about missing drivers / files / shared libraries, I will try to find out which deb package the file can be found in:

```
apt-file search swrast_dri.so
--> libgl1-mesa-dri: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
```

Then I will install that package

```
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri
```

and try again.

If `apt-file` isn't installed, you can install it by typing

```
sudo apt install apt-file
apt-file update
```

That being said, `anki` is one of the very few packages I'm downloading directly from their website [apps.ankiweb.net](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) because it's a very active project. Installation instructions are provided on the same page. If you do this, make sure to remove the packaged version from your system beforehand: `sudo apt remove anki`

Comment: I ran `apt-file search swrast_dri.so` and this was the output `libgl1-mesa-dri: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so
libgl1-mesa-dri: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
` , then I apt installed libgl1-mesa-dri. Still it doesn't seems to work

Comment: That's unfortunate.
In that case you can still try to install the version from anki's website. They package with all/most required libraries -- that has worked well for me in the past.
Another idea: do you have any plugins that could cause the issue?

Comment: I am installing anki from the official website for the first time.

Comment: You mean the problem is happening with anki installed from the official website?
In that case, try installing the ubuntu package and see if that works.

Comment: Due to some reason the profiles window works, but the main anki window doesn't work

Comment: Nope, the ubuntu version also doesn't work

Comment: What does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32056721/13853882 say, I couldn't understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124561/discussion-between-jcsjcs-and-mja).