# Poor Nvidia Driver Support

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, ubuntu-drivers

I'm currently running ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and on every single system update I have to reinstal the NVIDIA proprietary drivers, otherwise the computer is unusable. I followed the instructions to install the drivers at this link:

[How do I install the Nvidia driver for a GeForce GT 630](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver)

and have blacklisted nouveau. Can someone help me determine why the ubuntu update process causes issues with the NVIDIA drivers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, did you install the Nvidia drivers using the .run file downloaded from Nvidia's website?

Nvidia drivers need to be compiled against the kernel that's running, which is why whenever you do a system upgrade, you will have to reinstall the drivers. However, if you had installed using apt-get, the packages should have triggers on kernel updates.

You might want to uninstall the files installed by the .run and reinstall using apt-get.

Binary deb packages are available in Ubuntu's repository as nvidia-*

For example

```
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64.....run --uninstall
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
```

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly the information for which I was looking. Thanks!