# Losing NVIDIA-driver after updating system

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates

Why this happening every time i try to update via update manager (so, updates coming every day)? So, I need to reinstall NVIDIA-drivers every system update. It's getting REALLY annoying.

P.S. The reason I deleted nouveau and installed NVIDIA-driver --- Nouveau didn't let me to run SFML-apps...

**DKMS STATUS OUTPUT:**
*bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed

bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed

nvidia, 343.22, 3.13.0-39-generic, x86_64:installed*

Comment: How did you install the nVidia driver and which version? What's the output of `dmks status`? Usually `dkms` should recompile out-of-tree kernel modules on every kernel update.

Comment: You need to re-install the nvidia driver with each kernel upgrade or install it from the ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @DavidFoerster i used this tutorial http://askubuntu.com/a/451248/341889
DKMS STATUS OUTPUT:
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 343.22, 3.13.0-39-generic, x86_64:installed

Comment: @pushandpop: Please [edit] your question if you have something to add. It's much more difficult to find relevant info in the comments. Also program output is hard to read because of the wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Some drivers and apps depend on kernel code, so they need to be recompiled for each new kernel.  There is a system, DKMS, that alleviates this hassle.  You need to install DKMS from the repository.  I don't use special video drivers, but I do use DKMS for Virtualbox.

You can find some information [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1036788) that should explain it much better than I could.

Answer (score 0):

Do not install the nvidia driver from the manufacture's site as you will have to either rerun the installation with every single kernel update. Same goes for any driver that is not set up for apt-get to run dkms installation at kernel install. I recomment to just install the latest nvidia drivers from the ubuntu repos or if you want that "edge" run (!!!might break your installation, then again it might fix it!!!)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers-343 
sudo reboot
```

Now if it all fails horribly do not worry you just need to have access to your tty1 and internet after boot (if not try using the recovery option in grub and first select networking and then log as root).

```
sudo su
apt-get install ppa-purge 
ppa-purge xorg-edgers
reboot
be angry for wasting your time :P
```

Comment: I would not use the xorg-edgers repo, just install the nvid driver in the standard repositories (no need to install experimental packages).

Comment: which standard repos?

Comment: @pushandpop: I guess Bodhi Zazen means [Canonical's restricted repository](//i.stack.imgur.com/XlsXc.png), because that's the closest to official source nVidia drivers in Ubuntu.

Comment: Personally I prefer to install the packages from [ppa:xorg-edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=nvidia&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=) manually. That way I don't have to worry to pull in the many unstable upgrades to other X.Org components inadvertently.