# Ubuntu 14.04, NVidia GTX 750 double DVI output, only one DVI works

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I have two DVI outputs on GTX 750 NVidia card on my desktop running Ubuntu 14.04. One DVI works fine, the other doesn't seem to be working at all.

Monitor connected to second DVI can't register any signal. Cable I am using to connect it is OK, checked on different installations, driver is the latest (3.40\3.46).

Reinstalling drivers or changing `xorg.conf` manually didn't help.

Is it possible to configure two DVI ports on GTX 750 with Ubuntu 14.*?

```
    sudo lshw -C video
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GM107 [GeForce GTX 750]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:fb000000-fb07ffff
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with the new NVIDIA driver : 340.58 [found here](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/75019/en-us)

Installation is done as per [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver)