# libkmod: Error ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:686 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe./blacklist-nouveau.conf line 5 ignoring bad line starting with 'alia'

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel, nouveau

```
libkmod: Error ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:686 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe./blacklist-nouveau.conf line 5 ignoring bad line starting with 'alia'
```

[image: Phone picture of error]

I started getting this recently then today it fails to boot into Ubuntu just giving me a blank desktop background. I think it has to do with this manual way I went about installing the nvidia drivers? If it is how is the normal process for installing the drivers because this process is awkward to say the least!

[How do I install the Nvidia driver for a GeForce GT 630](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver)

Comment: I agree that the process described in the [the highest rated answer](/a/451248) is a bit “awkward” and I'm surprised nobody responded with the (to me) obvious and much more concise solution, before [I did just now](/a/564695).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the file  `/etc/modprobe/blacklist-nouveau.conf` contains the invalid verb `alia` in line 5 which should probably be `alias`. Are you sure you copied the code listing from the referred answer correctly? It should read:

```
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @MadMike: This is the precise answer. I would agree, that it needs to be fleshed out a bit. Encouraging people to post “lazy” incomplete answers as comments is a bad solution.