# NVIDIA drivers problem

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

i recently installed ubuntu 14.04LTS. My PC configuration is
Core-i7 4770
16GB RAM
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 760 
2TB HDD

I am new to Ubuntu. Before installing NVIDIA drivers the window transitions are slow and lagging. Then i installed NVIDIA drivers through the method in this link [How do I install the Nvidia driver for a GeForce GT 630](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver)
there were some problem while installing. I dont know whether everything went well or not. But at the end it said installation completed. after this the window transitions were very smooth and lag free. but then i noticed small glitches while using firefox or while using the NVIDIA settings in ubuntu. The icons too most of the time dont show up properly. How to solve this problem. And is there any other way to get NVIDIA drivers installed properly.?

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers/508255#508255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the current nvidia drivers installed and with the help of the below command,

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
```

After removing open the Terminal and login to your domain with the help of username and password. Use the below command and stop the graphic usage,

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Then try installing the nvidia again and start the installer,

```
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-*-331.38.run

sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-*-331.38.run
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting the following error                                alex@Alex-PC:~$ sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
[sudo] password for alex: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'nvidia-current' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 280 not upgraded.
alex@Alex-PC:~$                                                   What to do?