# Nvidia drivers just wont work, what do I do?

Tags: nvidia, display

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and I have 2 GTX 970's in my computer with three monitors. I want to utilize all the monitors while on Ubuntu but when ever I go to download the Nvidia drivers there are always issues that when I google it looks like there is a fix but never help me. I had to delete my partition and reinstall Ubuntu because I couldn't fix the issue of a black screen after grub. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Would have added a comment, but points wont allow.

See this askubuntu comment I gave some time ago. I'm not using same graphics card as you're doing, but installing your drivers using the Additional Drivers settings from Ubuntu is the easiest and most efficient way I found.

[How do I install the Nvidia driver for a GeForce GT 630](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver/542068#542068)

I tried installing using .sh from nvidia, amidst other options. I summarize what worked for me in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

for multi-monitors, before install Nvidia Drive, you should connect one monitor with mainboard's Integrated graphics. Others connect to Discrete graphics.

> start your computer. You'll view the monitor connected with mainboard is on
>
> during login interface, Ctrl+Alt+F2 login into terminal
>
> sudo apt-get purge nvidia or sudo apt-get autoremove nvidia(if you already install nvidia driver run these commands,or skip this step)
>
> sudo reboot(if you already install nvidia driver run these commands,or skip this step)
>
> Ctrl+Alt+F2 login into terminal again
>
> sudo service lightdm stop (stop lightdm service)
>
> sudo chmod+x ./filename.run
>   sudo ./filename.run (install nvidia drive)
>
> sudo reboot
>
> connect all your monitors to Discrete graphics

Done
Enjoy