# Nvidia Problem connection HDMI (Not detecting LG TV)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hdmi

I'm trying to connect LG-47LB650V to HP Pavilion-dv6-2190US that has GeForce GT 230M Via HDMI on Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAeWU.png

```
$ xrandr --verbose
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1280 x 720, maximum 1280 x 768
default connected primary 1280x720+0+0 (0x184) normal (normal) 0mm x 0mm
    Identifier: 0x183
    Timestamp:  35954
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
  1280x720 (0x184)    0.0MHz *current
        h: width  1280 start    0 end    0 total 1280 skew    0 clock    0.0KHz
        v: height  720 start    0 end    0 total  720           clock    0.0Hz
  1024x768 (0x185)   48.0MHz
        h: width  1024 start    0 end    0 total 1024 skew    0 clock   46.8KHz
        v: height  768 start    0 end    0 total  768           clock   61.0Hz
  800x600 (0x186)   29.3MHz
        h: width   800 start    0 end    0 total  800 skew    0 clock   36.6KHz
        v: height  600 start    0 end    0 total  600           clock   61.0Hz
  640x480 (0x187)   18.4MHz
        h: width   640 start    0 end    0 total  640 skew    0 clock   28.8KHz
        v: height  480 start    0 end    0 total  480           clock   60.0Hz
  1280x768 (0x188)    0.0MHz
        h: width  1280 start    0 end    0 total 1280 skew    0 clock    0.0KHz
        v: height  768 start    0 end    0 total  768           clock    0.0Hz
```

And

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT216M [GeForce GT 230M] (rev a2)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAcLH.png

I have tried all the listed drivers + installed `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.76.run` that messed up everything then I had to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

last year i bought a alienware with a nvidia . 
the first time i tried to connect this beauty to a hdmi tv i realize my laptop hdmi version was much newer than the tv's hdmi .

first i recommend you to try your laptop to other tv and see what hapend .

second in the setting panel , find the additional drivers icon and select the opcion : use nvidia binary driver .

if this docent work

try to use your intel hd video card and turn off the nvdia card

hope this help you .

if you have a dual grafic card like the intel hd and the nvidia .

Comment: Everything works fine with Windows so it's a driver problem, I have tried all the listed options here http://i.imgur.com/gnlxF55.png

Comment: why are you using the legacy driver ?? first try to change ir to the first one in your image (binary driver 331.113) that is the one im using  . other than that i let you a really good tread abaut nvidia drivers http://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver