# bluetooth not working on Lenovo Z50-70

Tags: wireless, nvidia, bluetooth, lenovo

I have new Lenovo Z50-70 with NVIDIA 820M graphics card. I am using 340v driver for it.

Bluetooth is not working, it says *bluetooth is disable* while wifi is working fine

output of `lsusb; lsmod | grep bluetooth; dmesg | grep firmware` is:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 5986:055e Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
bluetooth             446409  12 bnep,ath3k,btusb,rfcomm
6lowpan_iphc           18702  1 bluetooth
[   14.491624] Bluetooth: Error in firmware loading err = -110,len = 448, size = 4096
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every thing actually looks good but your bluetooth probably only works maybe every third boot.  This is what worked for me

```
echo "blacklist ath3k" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf
```

Then we edit a file to load ath3k later in the boot cycle
`gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local` and above the line that says `exit 0` put `sleep 10` and on the line below that put `modprobe ath3k` save, exit gedit and reboot.

The last 3 lines of the `/etc/rc.local` file should be

`sleep 10`

`modprobe ath3k`

`exit 0`

That should help with the firmware error as there is a timing issue with xhci_hcd that prevents ath3k from loading the firmware every time

NOTE: **Issue is resolved with kernel 3.16.0-32 or newer from Ubuntu without the above changes** per comment 12 at [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1429552) and also fixed now in 3.13.0-47 per [update log](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/3.13.0-47.78) see * Bluetooth: ath3k: workaround the compatibility issue with xHCI
    controller
    - LP: [#1400215](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1400215)

Comment: thanks man, but please can you or any of your friends help me with the nvidia driver problem?

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2260335&p=13206697#post13206697  says that this other post helped http://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver but they used nvidia-current

Comment: hey today I had the same issue again, I rebooted, still did not helped. what to do now?

Comment: I would edit the `/etc/rc.local` file and change it from `sleep 10` to `sleep 30` then save, exit, and reboot

Comment: sir, I am sorry, but bluetooth is not working at all after installing windows 8

Comment: If you can install kernel 3.16.0-32, the issue is fixed in Ubuntu `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic`  You may have to enable proposed repository in software and updates and do another `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and a reboot to get 3.16.0-32 loaded.  If you need bluetooth to work in Win, go to lenovo.com and see if you can download the Qualcom bluetooth drivers

Comment: what i meant was after installing windows 8 i am not able to use bluetooth on ubuntu

Comment: So are you booting into Windows and rebooting into Ubuntu, or do you shut down from Win8 and power it back up and go into Ubuntu?

Comment: I shutdown windows completely and then power up ubuntu

Comment: Are there any firmware or bluetooth errors in dmesg?  Check to see if ath3k and btusb are still being loaded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21923/discussion-between-edward-torvalds-and-jeremy31).

Comment: sir if i put my laptop to sleep and resume i found bluetooth disabled, i ran `modprobe ath3k` but no use, i had to restart computer to get it working, i am using linux kernel v3.19

Comment: oops i forgot to say i am on ubuntu 15.04 :p

Comment: After resume try `sudo modprobe -r ath3k` then `sudo modprobe ath3k`

Comment: please help me out with this problem: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/311045/52733