# Graphics card not being detected

Tags: nvidia, graphics

My graphics card isn't being detected by Ubuntu. It's running off the on board graphics not my EVGA GeForce GTX 750ti FTW. I'm not sure what to do and I'm not sure how to download my drivers.

Comment: Is it detected by the BIOS? You may need to enter the BIOS and turn it on by changing a setting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 install NVIDIA driver](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver)

Answer (score 0):

Open a Terminal and use the following commands in order and enter your password when it asks you:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

This will install the latest nvidia drivers for your graphics card if it is not recognized in the additional drivers tab in software & updates.

Comment: That worked but my resolution is only 1280 x 1024p when I have a 1920 x 1080p monitor. Can You help me with this?

Comment: It installs a control panel where you can adjust the resolution :) search for nvidia on the menu.