# 14.04 Nvidia graphics drama - How can I get back into the install?

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I bought a Nvidia GTX 750 to support 3x monitors, and then installed the card, machine boots to flashing cursor top left only - no input possible.

Googled the problem - added the OEM driver (I think) from a ppa. Now the system won't boot with either graphics card - original and new card get to flashing cursor (followed this guide - http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/03/install-nvidia-driver-334-21-ubuntu-linux/)

Not at login screen, and Ctrl + Alt + F1-6 do nothing.

I only really need to get back into the drive to rescue data. I have a spare drive, clean install, old graphics card that I'm working from now. I can boot back into the old drive via a USB caddy is needed.

Frustratingly I encrypted the home dir, and the passphrase in a txt file on that desktop dir. (I know, I know). I have the password for the user account of course.

1. Can I boot into the drive in anyway (at least to get the passphrase)
2. Any working suggestions of how to get the new card to work. Clearly I'm nervous - my last attempted has seemingly lost all my work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, boot with a live CD or DVD to access all the data on the hard drive (although that isn't possible with encryption).

If you only encrypted your home folder, we can make a small modification, remove the file with this path:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

That may allow you to get to a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

The add the Xorg Edgers PPA, follow these instructions:

> Add the xorg-edgers PPA first:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
> ```
>
> Then, update your package list:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> ```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/472104/186134)

And then install the current driver with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

I have to say, I have serious problems with dual screen display, but I have 2 cards. Is yours a single or double head, and what are the ports?

Comment: "remove the file with this path"  - which file am I removing?... I'm running dual head fine on old card (1x hdmi, 1x vga) - new card has 1x hdmi, 1x vga and 1x dvi dual link))

Comment: The file with the path `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

Comment: Ah. OK - if that doesn't work, will it kill any thing? is it better to change its name?

Comment: yeah, rename to `xorg.conf.bck` idf you want!

Comment: There was no `xorg.conf`. There was `xorg.conf.06052015`. I renamed that one. I also took `xorg.conf.failsafe`, copied / renamed it `xorg.conf` and then deleted it, in case it was a hidden file I couldn't see. I was in the dir via `sudo nautilus` to hopefully also unmask hidden files. That didn't change anything.