# Nvidia crashes after updating ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and Nvidia driver on my PC. After updating Ubuntu, Nvidia crashes and this is my new Ubuntu desktop:

[image]

When I enter to tty and run `DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace` I see blank screen with mouse pointer and only can right click on the desktop and access right click options but no close, maximize, minimize buttons or shadows, only can move windows.

After that, I managed to switch to Nouveau and see **no problem**, Also **Nvidia works with ubuntu-gnome** desktop!

### What I already did

I tested all these solutions but none of them works:

1. Followed all these solutions but none of them solved my problem:

   - https://askubuntu.com/a/451248
   - https://askubuntu.com/a/76951
   - https://askubuntu.com/a/290376
2. Updated system again.
3. Reinstalling (purging and then installing) nvidia-304, nvidia-prime, ubuntu-desktop, unity.
4. In grub menu, going to advanced options and load older kernel version then reinstalling Nvidia driver.

### System information

**Display adapter:** NVIDIA GeForce 7300 SE/7200 GS

**Processor:** AMD athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual core Processor 4000+

Thank You.

### UPDATE

Output of command `lsmod | grep nvidia`:

```
nvidia              11360265  36 
drm                   303102  1 nvidia
```

Content of file: Xorg.0.log: [Click here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11861660/).

Comment: I have same problems after core upgrating. What says glxinfo ?

Comment: See http://paste.ubuntu.com/11876905/ for glxinfo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar problem two months ago with ubuntu 14.04 after an update. My PC is running a nvidia geforce 7300 gs. Not exactly the same card as yours, but maybe the solution I applied will work for you as well.
I uninstalled nvidia-304 driver and installed the nvidia-173. This is not a perfect solution, because I still encountered some minor issues, namely while switching to another account, and sometimes I need to login twice to enter my session.

Before login, go to a terminal (CTRL-ALT-F1), login and execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-304
sudo apt-get install nvidia-173
```

Comment: Yes! installing nvidia-173 solved the problem. Thank you :)

Comment: After more investigations, I found that there is an issue between compiz and nvidia drivers, due to a bug inside compiz (no ref because from memory, and I moved to recent hardware since). I installed a ubuntu derivative not requiring compiz: I chose linux mint with cinnamon (with nvidia-304 installed) and the issue was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem years ago. Solving it essentially required aggressively removing **all** nvidia program files. Please note that the use of "--purge" when uninstalling the nvidia package did not seem to remove the offending nvidia program(s). I had to do a subsequent file search using "nvidia" to locate residual nvidia packages(?).

Please see my post: [Fixing/Repairing a Blank (Black) Screen in Ubuntu 13.04](http://srynas.blogspot.com/2013/08/fixingrepairing-blank-black-screen-in.html). Please note that this post is nearly two years old and I have not had a subsequent issue.

I see that you have a "AMD athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual core Processor". One of my computers is also an AMD athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual core Processor that utilizes an nvidia graphics card. Occasionally the text gets scrambled but this has been happening less frequently. I assume in response to bug fixes.

Have your tried using "X.ORGXserver - Nouveau display driver"? It now seems to work fairly reliably. It is located under "System Settings" --> "Software & Updates" --> "Additional Drivers". Also, my screen identifies, as a possible selection, the Nvidia binary driver version 331.113. As with the Nouveau drive, it occasionally scrambles text. The simple solution when that occurs, is to reboot.

Comment: Yes. As i previously mentioned, Nouveau works but it have high CPU usage on my system. My problem is nvidia just on ubuntu desktop!.

Comment: It appears that I do not have anything further to offer. For my computers, I am using the Nouveau driver. The current available nvidia driver is version 331.113. Is that your available version? You may wish to modify your question to identify which nvidia driver you are attempting to use.

Comment: I specific driver in my question, that's nvidia-304 for nvidia 7 series. Thank you for answering my questions :)

Comment: I am not sure that I really helped. Have you tried updating to a newer nvidia driver?  <br \>  <a href="https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia">Ubuntu Nvidia Documentation</a>

Comment: Maybe the problem is from new version of unity or compiz, If not, why nvidia works well on gnome and xubuntu desktops?

Comment: Considering the complexity of computers, it can be daunting finding why something is failing. I have three computers (one of which is an AMD 64 X2 Dual core Processor) which all have nvidia graphics cards. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. The AMD 64 computer has occasional video hiccups, nothing as significant as your concern. Sorry that I could not have helped more.