# How to test if my laptop components is already working?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, webcam

I previously test to run Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS from the disk to try if my hardwares will work. I've test the WiFi and the graphics card, the WiFi works but the graphics card nvdia geforce gt 720m is need to be installed. I also want to test if my built in webcam is already working before I proceed to reformat my laptop, but I can't find a way to test it.

- My question is how can I check if my webcam is working?
- And should use the additional driver installer built in inside Ubuntu
  14.04.2 LTS to install my nvidia geforce gt 720m or download it from the nvdia website and install it in the way that I know?

Comment: simplest would be using an application to see it perform: `cheese` will allow you to use your webcam

Comment: "And should use the additional driver installer built in inside Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS to install my nvidia geforce gt 720m or download it from the nvdia website and install it in the way that I know?" is probably a matter of opinion. My opinion: if the native one works why bother with the one from the nvidia website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Ubuntu < 14.04 Download and install **Cheese** using the following steps:

- Open a terminal window.
- Type in the following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install cheese
  ```

If you use Ubuntu 14.04 cheese is installed by default(thanks for [@kos](https://askubuntu.com/users/380067/kos) note )

- Run Cheese. Cheese should automatically detect your webcam and
  display live video stream.

source and more information would be found on  [this community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam) wiki

---

to install nvidia run:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

more info would be founded [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver)

Comment: +1 but I'm sure that `cheese` is installed by default in Trusty

Comment: @kos thanks for your note, i'll edit my answer