# Infinite Login Loop (not permissions issue) - proprietary NVIDIA driver install gone wrong

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, login, 14.10

I've got an infinite login loop issue that I need help with.

Let me start at the beginning.

I followed instructions from here:
[Ubuntu 14.04 install NVIDIA driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver)

Result of my lspci | grep VGA is:

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF100 [GeForce GTX 465] (rev a3)
```

I followed the more upvoted answer (the second one).

First I used wget to download the drivers from here: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/75019/en-us

Then:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia* && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This went well, no errors. Then I added

```
    blacklist nouveau
    blacklist lbm-nouveau
    options nouveau modeset=0
    alias nouveau off
    alias lbm-nouveau off
```

To a new file, /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf

At this point I rebooted.

I logged into tty1, and continued to follow the instructions.

I ran:

```
sudo stop lightdm
```

This resulted in the expected "lightdm stopped/waiting" output.

Then I ran

```
sudo bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.67.run
```

This same hardware has previously used the 331 drivers from apt-get with this version of Ubuntu without issue - so I have good reason to believe 331 is the right driver version.

The script ran, it mentioned a pre-install script failed to run - I assumed this was its failure to install proper dependencies. I continued with the install even though there was a pre-install error.

It completed successfully, and as the instructions indicated, I ran

```
sudo apt-get install dkms fakeroot build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

since I assumed this was what the pre-install error was about.

During the install I did opt for it to make the xorg configuration files for me (nivida-xconfig).

I rebooted, and it didn't even get to the login screen - seemingly eternal maroon, followed by a hung terminal: a black screen with an idle _

I logged back into tty1 to fish around, I removed the blacklist and ran the install script with the --uninstall parameter. It set the config file back and claimed to successfully uninstall.

I figured I could just try

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-331-updates
```

Just as I had before (since this proprietary driver install failed).

This however failed - apparently in conflict with two packages: 
nvidia-persistenced
and something like xorg-driver-... something (memory is failing me here).

So far so good, I reboot.
I get the normal login screen - things are looking up. I login, and the screen goes black for a second (seemingly normal - I expect the desktop to load now), but install it starts up another login screen. This happens over and over without change.

Again, I login at tty1. .Xauthority is owned by my user - that's not the issue as I read when others have had this problem.

I tried reinstalling xorg at this point:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg
```

No luck though.

UPDATE:

Running

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
```

separate from trying to install nvidia-331-updates succeeds in the install.

Now the login occurs - but without any of the normal gnome stuff ... I have terminal open at startup (lucky in this case), and I can open Firefox and browser - but there is no window management, no top bar to close windows or turn off the computer - no left bar to switch between apps... just my background and top-bar-less windows... :O

I am thinking this has to do with Unity versus gnome xsessions - but looking in the /usr/share/xsessions directory I only see ubuntu.desktop (which I think is Unity?)

I suspect NVIDIA install script did this... but I don't yet know how to recover from it.

What do you guys think it is?

Many thanks for spending time reading about my problem.
If you know someone who might know the answer - please forward this to them.

Much obliged,

Brandon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to run:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep nvidia-331
```

or similar, before installation. I'm on my phone right now but you can run

```
apt-get --help
```

If you get command not found. This should install the dependencies needed to execute the build.

Comment: seemed to be working, but then I got `/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` and `Failed to process build dependencies`. This happens right after `Setting up xserver-xorg-dev` and `Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-10ubuntu2.3) ...`

:/ not seeing anything relevant to why nvidia-331 build dependencies would fail...

Comment: @bfosterscripps are you absolutely sure you are running 14.04 because libc-bin version 2.19-10ubuntu2.3 is for 14.10?

Comment: @bfosterscripps first of all, I believe 14.10 is EOL. Next, I personally had trouble building nividia from source on 14.10 and seem to remember having the same error you described (except I was building the legacy driver instead of 331). 14.10 uses mir so it is different from 14.04 that uses regular old x11.

Comment: So sorry- it suggested the wrong tag, and I didn't catch that. I am running Utopic. I like it better than Vivid, which was taking forever to shut down and had bugs with VLC and other apps...

So it may be EOL, but I prefer it.

I think nvidia is installed correctly now - with nvidia-331 driver... I can login and my startup apps start - I even get a notification about the chat service not connecting... but now there isn't a window management system - no top bar to move the windows with or close them - it's really odd.

Comment: It might be related to lightdm or gdm? I'm not sure which Utopic uses out of the box- but I noticed lightdm doesn't have a .conf file, and `/usr/share/xsessions` only has ubuntu.desktop - which looks to be a Unity file? There isn't a default gnome desktop file, which should be here... :/

Comment: @bfosterscripps nope, the lightdm conf file is nolonger in use. we now use individual files that are located in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` you should have a file in that directory called `50-unity-greeter.conf`. Despite what the internet may tell you, Unity is not gnome, Unity is a compiz plugin which brings us to the next problem. Install compizconfig-settings-manager and then launch it by running `ccsm`. Then, scroll down to the unity plugin and enable it.

Comment: I have no `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` directory...

I installed with `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` and launched ccsm. I enabled the Unity plugin - there was a conflict with the Show Desktop flag, so I disabled the Show Desktop in favor of Unity. There were some dependencies that were installed when I enabled the Unity plugin as well, and as soon as it was done "enabling" Unity, the left bar and normal looking desktop came back.
Now the only issue is, even though it looks normal - it doesn't behave that way: when I dry to drag windows around it doesn't move.

Comment: the above issue of not being able to reposition windows is true even after reboot. Looking into what might be causing that now.

I'm a little spooked that I have no `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d`

Comment: I solved the moving windows issue - there is a setting under "general" for `Move Window` - I just had to enable it.

Out of curiosity - what is the best way to install nvidia drivers? Is it just `sudo apt-get install nvidia-331` - or looking at the results of `ubuntu-drivers devices` and installing what is recommended?
Is the Unity bit there by default, and just by installing `ccsm` I can enable it?

Basically - if I had to do it right from the beginning, what set of instructions could I follow?

Comment: @bfosterscripps it's probably best to look at the results of `ubuntu-drivers devices`. Next: yes, unity is there by default and you can enable it. It should be enabled by default, however . . .

Comment: @bfosterscripps this was previously not an option. On newer versions, there is a plugin for unity listed in ccsm that you can enable. Sometimes when you upgrade from an older version of ubuntu (12.04 for example), this plugin is disabled because the user settings are migrated from a version from when this option did not exist and so it needs to be enabled. I don't think this is much of an issue upgrading from newer versions as you usually don't have to enable the plugin, only when there is an issue.