# blank screen from nvidia on ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, screen

I installed Nvidia drivers using th[e official method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) and also as advised [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver/542068#542068) by Rexford.

I still ended up with a black/blank screen. Addidtinally, i couldnt uninstall using `apt-get purge nvidia*`under `ctrl-alt-f1`. I've definitely read and redownloaded many times.

`sudo dkms autoinstall` gives no output

`glxinfo` says `unable to open display`

`lsof | grep nvidia` show nvidia is available

`modprobe -R nvidia` shows the installed nvidia_346

`lspci -vnn | grep -I VGA -A 12` shows `kernel driver in use: i915` but also shows my graphics card clearly.

Any ideas??

Comment: You tried this? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia#Low.2FMissing_Screen_Resolutions

Comment: Any ideas on how I can use that please? Can't open xrandr right now. Screen is black.

Comment: Oops. That's the wrong section. Here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia#Screen_Blanks.2FMonitor_Turns_Off

Comment: Initially, I had the lgon sound with no scrern, mentioned under Screen Blanks/Monitor Turns Off.     I was a bit unfortunate to mis-type /etc/X11/... with a small x so I missed out on that simple help and dived deep into the unknown..

Comment: What do you mean by "I think I got it?"

Comment: I'd got the section, typing from a tablet.        How can u start afresh? I can't delete the erring nvidia drivers.

Comment: Have you tried to to what's listed there?

Comment: I have done it.

Comment: Going here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia#Installation_without_X_.2F_from_the_console to try and start again.

Comment: Ps, I've blacklisted the i915 too

Comment: I've finally removed nvidia drivers by typing the entire command `apt-get --purge remove nvidia-36`.  I'm up now,  how do iIinstall NVIDIA??

Comment: OK. Did it work?

Comment: Drivers are not installed right now.

Comment: Reboot and see if you still have a blank screen. We can work from there if everything's back to normal.

Comment: After removing the nvidia,  I managed to get in.  But, I don't have the drivers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28877/discussion-between-nyxee-and-zacharee1).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28961/discussion-between-nyxee-and-zacharee1).

Answer (score 0):

I stopped lightdm using 'service stop lightdm'

Then enabled nvidia-graphics using 'sudo prime-select nvidia'

I edited /etc/X11/xorg.conf to look like this (exactly):

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
EndSection
```

Then made it un-editeable by any process using:

```
chattr +i xorg.conf
```

Note: if you want to make it editable again, just use

```
chattr -i xorg.conf
```

Then, I disabled a component of Nvidia called `gpu-manager` by commenting out all the lines in `/etc/init/gpu-manager.conf`

Then restarted X using `service start lightdm'.

to retrun to the intel GPU, re-enable `gpu-manager`, make `xorg.conf` editeable again, activate intel mode using `sudo prime-select intel` and restart X using `service lightdm start`.

Summarized from [Solving the Ubuntu 14.04 – NVIDIA 346 – nvidia-prime black screen issue](http://vxlabs.com/2015/02/05/solving-the-ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-346-nvidia-prime-black-screen-issue/).

Comment: There was a minor hiccup, **window menus disappeared** (which I noticed thanks to  having startup window programs) and the **unity launcher disappeared**  too. I realised that stopping and starting lightdm solved the issue until my next reboot. When I made lightdm default via **`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`** the issue looks  sooved permanently.   I had previously deleted `~/config/dconf` but the problem had re-surfaced many hours later.