# Ubuntu 14.04 mouse and keyboard focus different windows

Tags: 14.04, windows, keyboard, mouse, focus

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS and my mouse and keyboard are behaving weird after login today and after opening one window (firefox, nautilus) and then the terminal (terminator). Mouse and keyboard are both focusing different windows and I cannot click another window or the unity logo, just the window the mouse has focus on.

Info:

- It worked seamless for a good month and this behaviour happened just today.
- Last thing I installed: Wine
- Last settings I changed: Set gedit as default editor with Ubuntu Tweak
- Keyboard: Logitech K270
- Mouse: Logitech M705
- Happens with laptop touchpad, too.
- Happens on Unity and Gnome.
- Rebooting does not fix this problem.
- Cannot upgrade Ubuntu because I need to use ROS indigo.

I found other threads, where people had focus problems, but it was due to using gamer mice. And as I said, everything worked before.

Is there an easy way to fix this behavior? I cannot think of any cause and can barely work on Ubuntu like this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unplug the Logitech USB dongle, reboot, and see if the touchpad works normally. Open Language Settings and see what the keyboard input method is set to. Report back.

Comment: I have two dongles. One for mouse (unifying dongle) and one normal dongle for the keyboard. After rebooting without the keyboard dongle, everything seems to work normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

*Unplug the Logitech USB dongle, reboot, and see if the touchpad works normally. Open Language Settings and see what the keyboard input method is set to.*

Unplugging the Logitech keyboard dongle allowed everything else to operate as normal.

For the unifying dongle, re-pair your Logitech mouse, and update the firmware in the dongle. Then retry the keyboard dongle again.

To upgrade the firmware in the Logitech unifying dongle, see https://community.logitech.com/s/question/0D531000055gw8YCAQ/logitech-response-to-unifying-receiver-research-findings for instructions and the firmware.

You might also check the USB settings in your BIOS. They may need to be set to USB 2.0, or legacy.

Lastly, you might have to plug the dongles directly into your computer's USB ports, instead of a hub (if you're using one).

Comment: Thank you very much! I cannot see a way to upgrade the firmware for Ubuntu on the mentioned page, but it's not necessary, because I am using a different keyboard now and it works like a charm. I wouldn't have thought that a dongle can create such peculiar behavior on Ubuntu.

Comment: @S.M.  The firmware update requires Windows to do the update.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to similar focus problem. A part of it was that mouse focus remained locked to one window but keyboard focus was in another. I fixed it by running:

```
sudo apt install wmctrl
xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/click_to_focus -s true 
wmctrl -R WindowName 
xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/click_to_focus -s false
```

Here are the links to [original answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774888/mouse-focus-problem) and [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wmctrl/+bug/1641608)