# Nvidia drivers on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I'd like to install the proper Nvidia drivers on my system, it's got a GTX 860M, but `lspci | grep VGA|3D` returns:

`00:02.0 Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)`

And further inspection to see which controller is active by `lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA`
 returns:

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])`

The last time I tried to install NVidia drivers directly I ended up not being able to boot my system because the screen went to black on boot and was unresponsive to go into terminal-only mode.

So I'm wondering how to proceed?

EDIT: I mean 14.04, unfortunate typo in title :(

EDIT: The last time I attempted to install a NVidia driver (which ended in an unusable OS) I'm fairly certain I did something akin to [the long answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver)

Thanks for any help,

Robert

Comment: did you try http://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver ? if so, update your question aas to what you have tried and what happened.

Comment: I'm fairly certain I tried to do that, or something very similar.  That is uninstalling the current driver, blacklisting nouveau and further stopping the DM and installing. Which resulted in booting to a black screen and not being able to access the terminal version etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properly working NVIDIA drivers for GEFORCE GTX 860M as of now are drivers 352 or 361. The drivers 352 are available in the Ubuntu repositories, the drivers 361 are available from the Proprietary GPU drivers PPA. To achieve the best possible installation results, install the latest stable drivers 361 from the NVIDIA long-lived branch by following these instructions. But first remove all NVIDIA software you currently have tried to install ... open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install NVIDIA drivers 361 and Optimus support.
Select the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password and then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Important : Set a <kbd>Space</kbd> between the last character in the `linux` line and `nouveau.modeset=0`.

To check whether the NVIDIA drivers installation was successful ... open a terminal and execute :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

The output shall show that you are using the NVIDIA adapter : `Kernel driver in use: nvidia`.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501
Kernel driver in use: i915

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: This fix also works well for **Nvidia Quadro K1200** (Ubuntu 14.04.4), which otherwise black-screens (or patterns) and is non-responsive.

Comment: I ended up updating to 16.04 but thank you so very much for a very informative post.

Comment: Trying this as fix for **Nvidia Quadro K1200**, for Ubuntu **16.04.1 (64-bit)**. Was working, but issue with *uncontrolled screen-flicker* on monitor wakeup.