# Graphic issues after Ubuntu 16.04 with [Nvidia GTX 970] - second screen flickering/turns black

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, multiple-monitors

From [Graphics issues after installing Ubuntu 16.04 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics) I can say that I've tried all the different drivers and even the `nouveau` won't work. Tried the `purge` and what follows in different variations as listed. I've been running `16.04` since it got out and the problem occured two days ago starting with the second screen flickering after an hour or two, and then it turns black. Now it turns black almost immediatlely after boot or awakening from sleep. Ubuntu detects the second screen at screen settings and the third screen works properly, but it uses the `hdmi` input so I guess that's that.

Edit 1: just wanted to add that I've tried fresh reinstall of the system and don't have secure boot. This is a problem that have endured the whole summer and I've sadly not found a solution yet.

Edit 2: Just done the purge method explained in the link again with the newest `nvidia` driver `370.28`, without success.

Edit 3: Still not working as of `375.26`.

Edit 4: Not working as of `378.13`, however (and this will sound funny and make someone laugh) I've found out that a temporary solution for me, is by turning off and on the second screen somewhere between 10-25 times. This makes it stay on the rest of the day for reasons unknown to me.

Any help will be more than appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having similar issues, but with Nvidia K1200 (16.04.1). Trying suggestions from: http://askubuntu.com/questions/763874/nvidia-drivers-on-14-04

Comment: Yes well that suggestion is similar to the link i provide i.e. purge install manually. I have already tried that with all the drivers avalable with no result.

Comment: Using which PPA or driver(s)?

Comment: 367 right now. There was an update to that driver today, but nothing changed after install/reboot.

Comment: I tried **nvidia-361** (from **ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa**), which stopped the original issue (uncontrolled flicker) on wakeup (from screen blanked). However, still occurs with KVM switch (returning to Ubuntu 16.04, from Win10 1607). Have now changed to **nvidia-364** ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. Turns out that some of the transistors in the screen were defect. Screen is old and I should've tested another screen immediately after I had tried the reinstall/driver changes with no luck. Bought a new screen and problem was solved!