# ubuntu gnome 16.04 freezes after login

Tags: nvidia, gnome, 16.04, freeze

If i have my second display pluged in everything freezes after a couple of seconds after login. 
I'm running version 16.04.
The grahpics card is a gtx960m and i have driver version 361.42.
It only happens if i have a second display pluged in and after rebooting 3 or more time it sometimes doesnt freeze.
I dont know what to do.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is probably wrong with your graphics card driver.

Had the same problem with ubuntu 14.04 and geforce gtx 860M.
Updated driver and added prime-indicator to make sure that I was using the desired card all the time. (runs the same card for all processes)
You can use bumblebee to choose card for each process separately.

## For updating Driver:

[How do I install the Nvidia driver for a GeForce GT 630](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver)

## For installing prime-indicator:

http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch.html

Comment: my addionall driver says the newest is 361.42. but if i try to install nvidia-current it wants to install 304 wich one should i have?

Comment: 361.42 , that should work...