# How to change display resolution? xrandr and X -configure failed

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, xorg, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

## Short explanation:

The problem in short is that changing my display resolution to what I want it to be fails, but works in Windows. I tried using xrandr and that failed with a `BadMatch` error. And after that I tried to create an xorg.conf file with `X -configure` in root shell, but that failed with the error `Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices. Configuration failed.` **How can I cange my screen resolution?**

## Long explanation:

### My Setup

I want to start with that I'm new to ubuntu and just installed the system and the nvidia driver following [these](https://askubuntu.com/a/700613/579074) steps And now the system specs I think are relevant:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

CPU: i5-4460
GPU: GTX 970
1. Monitor: acer M230HDL (works perfectly)
2. Monitor: Philips 190S8 (works with wrong resolution) [Manual with a lot of information.](http://linfotech.co.uk/schematics/Philips/Philips%20190s8_190v8.pdf)

### First Try

1.

```
$ cvt 1280 1024 60   
# 1280x1024 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.31M4) hsync: 63.67 kHz; pclk: 109.00 MHz
Modeline "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
```

2.

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  108.88  1280 1360 1496 1712  1024 1025 1028 1060  -HSync +Vsync
```

3.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3072 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected 1152x864+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00 +
   1360x768      59.96    59.80  
   1152x864      60.00* 
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
   680x384       59.96    59.80  
   640x480       59.94  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       72.19  
   320x240       60.05  
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  60.00    59.94    50.00    49.95    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00    50.08  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1280x1024_60.00 (0x30f) 108.880MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1360 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock  63.60KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1060           clock  60.00Hz
```

4.

```
$ xrandr --addmode DVI-I-1 1280x1024_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
Serial number of failed request:  47
Current serial number in output stream:  48
```

### Second try

1. Boot into root shell.
2. Make / read-write `mount -o remount,rw /`
3. ```
   $ X -configure
   some output (will add if asked)
   Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices. Configuration failed.
   ```

## The Quesion

**How the hell do I

a) get a modeline that will work with my second monitor?

b) get a xorg.conf that I can edit so that I can change the resolution in there?**