# Resolution at 480 x 620

Tags: drivers, graphics, display-resolution

I am quite new to Ubuntu and just booted recently it onto my built PC from a USB Stick. Everything works but the screen resolution is at 480x680.

I tried:

- Going into Display, but the only options I have is 480 x 680.
- I did xrandr - s 2560x1440 (my resolution) and it says my min is 480x680, current is 480x680, and max 480x680... ah?!
- I looked at similar posts but they do not seem to apply to me. I am not running Virtual Box, and  do not have any other OS but the current version of Ubuntu.

(I also checked drivers, yet the only one I have is: "Using Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPU from intel-microcode. Also, my mobo is from MSI H110M, graphics card NVIDA GTX 1060, and CPU Intel i5 6600.)

I hope to be able to use Ubuntu! Any help appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to install your Nvidia drivers, either opensource (from Ubuntu) or proprietary (from Nvidia).

Read this question: [How do I install the Nvidia driver for a GeForce GT 630](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver)