# Can't login with GUI in 14.04.05

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I installed some recommended updates today and now when I get to the login screen I cannot login on my account or the guest account. When I try, it takes me to black screen and then returns to the login screen. I can login on the command line in the terminal. .Xauthority has the correct ownership. 
Any ideas as to what is going wrong? 
When it is booting, I get a message saying that it is booting in an insecure environment, I think this is because it asked me to turn "secure boot" off, which I did, but it hasn't prompted me to re-enter the secure booy password.

Comment: Login to one tty and check your user "home" directory permission,

Comment: It seems to have the correct permissions as well. My home directory has my user ID set as the owner.

Comment: Did you take the HWE update and do you have AMD or NVIDIA graphics?

Comment: NVIDIA graphics card. What is the HWE update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending five hours trying different solutions, re-installing the NVIDIA driver is what fixed it. I'm assuming that is because the NVIDIA driver is 3rd party and was built on the kernel I was using before the update.

[How to install the NVIDIA driver](https://askubuntu.com/a/700613/589853)

Comment: You probably installed the driver a wrong way. If you install it right, it will rebuild automatically.