# Problem installing video driver in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon, amd-processor

I tried all possibilities that I found on the Internet to install drivers, but all I get is blank screen, errors and errors, I'm new to Ubuntu and don`t know very much, I used windows 7, now wanted to check out Ubuntu.

Really I like but I'm bad feeling that I don't understand this OS, if I can't install a simple driver, please help me.
I have Acer Aspire 7535 notebook in terminal its show that I have:

```
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS780M [Mobility Radeon HD 3200]
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4530/4570/545v]
```

I tried install from AMD's home page drivers, tried to install/Uninstall fglrx, all possible ways that I can find on the Internet, and none of these is working. Hope that someone can help me

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/9465/186134