# NVIDIA driver doesn't install correctly

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, unity-dash

I just finished building my new desktop which has a NVIDIA GPU. The Ubuntu installation went well, but I noticed that the launcher was off. When the dash was opened, I only saw a solid color and nothing was behind the dash.

I came to the conclusion that the system was using the default video driver which did not support 3D features. I tried to install an NVIDIA driver via terminal (added a repo, then did an update, then installed a driver with it, no `.run` file). Once I restarted the system, the display looked odd, I did not have the regular Ubuntu boot. The resolution was off, and once I logged in, I saw some code, then it put me back into the log in screen.

I currently use Ubuntu 15.10 and the "`xorg-edgers`" repositories.

Comment: What commands did you run to install the drivers?

Comment: The following commands. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-343
sudo reboot`

Comment: Not sure why add a PPA. 15.10 has newer packages in the repositories, namely nvidia-346 and nvidia-352. It's also not hard to install: http://askubuntu.com/a/9465/20054

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xorg-edgers PPA does not contain newer NVIDIA drivers anymore.
Additional drivers now are located in the Proprietary GPU Drivers PPA.

But you only need to add this PPA in case the drivers from the Ubuntu repositories do not work.
First remove NVIDIA software you already have installed and also remove the xorg-edgers PPA.

The most proper way to handle drivers installation is to perform this from a virtual console.
On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter your user name and password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge  
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa  
sudo reboot
```

After the restart install the stable **NVIDIA drivers 352** from the official Ubuntu repositories.
On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter your user name and password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

Comment: In addition, would this work in other versions, like 14.04 LTS and so on?

Comment: @weezle1234 : Yes, this works on all supported editions of Ubuntu. :)