Ubuntu 22.04 failed startup after updating from ubuntu 20.04
I have updated my system from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 then to 20.04 and at last to 22.04.
After updating to Ubuntu 22.04, the system fails to start up! giving the ACPI BIOS Error
.
I even tried to boot from a usbdisk (try Ubuntu option) but it also didn't work!

After going through ACPI error, it loads Ubuntu logo then a black screen with a flashing dash appears and nothing happens!

I would be thankful to anyone help me fix this.

The ACPI messages are most likely irrelevant, I think the issue is with the vga drivers. You can try adding nomodeset to the boot parameters to see if that's the issue, at that pont you probably want to try and reinstall the vga drivers. See https://askubuntu.com/a/38834/380067

I added nomodeset but nothing has changed!

Ok, try the following: boot again into GRUB, this time select recovery mode and boot into recovery mode, you should get a root prompt. Try and run apt install -f, if that doesn't fix it try and reinstall the vga driver following the instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/a/9465/380067 . I'm not sure what's going on exactly but these are the two things I'd try first.
